# Beamer warning: large interlaced PNG might cause out of memory

Tags: beamer, png, memory

I have a long Beamer presentation that gave me no errors or warnings on texlive 2013, but since I upgraded to texlive 2015, I get the following warning:

> large interlaced PNG might cause out of memory (use non-interlaced PNG
>   to fix this)

However, it does not indicate the line where this happens, making it a potentially arduous task to debug this... So how should I proceed here?

How can I identify the PNG causing trouble in a big Beamer presentation?

How can I make the PNG "non-interlaced"?

Many thanks!

Comment: never seen that, but the message is from pdftex not the macro package such as beamer or latex. isn't it given at the point the image is included? so you should see from the log which page you are on, you presumably can't have _that_ many images on each page?

Comment: But the log is not giving me the line in the code where the problem occurs... and I have 50+ slides... Do you suggest to compile each slide separately? What do you mean with "I should see in the log which page I am on"? I cannot see that...

Comment: tex always outputs [1], [2] etc as it ships out each page

Comment: I really do not understand what you mean, I am on Beamer, do you mean slides instead of pages? In Texstudio log I usually get the line in the code (not the page) where the error/warning occurs, but in this case it is empty

Comment: Well, it is a warning, not an error. Thus, the main question is if you are worried about if your PDF presentation will work on known or unknown computers. In the first case, just test the PDF.  In the second, it is safer avoid any interlaced image (no just some image)  to ensure that the PDF can be showed in computers with less memory. Use `convert -interlace none` to save your day.

Comment: Since the offending PNG cannot be spotter, I guess a one-liner to convert all the pngs in a folder to non-interlace mode keeping the same names would be a good answer for this question.

Comment: @DaniCee Look at the `.log` file, not the snippets texstudio is filtering out. In the  complete logfile you will see the page marker `[2]` when beamer start a new page and you will see when an image is included. From this you should be able to narrow down the image which is causing this warning.

Comment: @Fran Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

> converting [Fran's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327126/beamer-warning-large-interlaced-png-might-cause-out-of-memory#comment800528_327126) into a CW answer

To avoid interlaced images, these can be converted by using

```
 convert -interlace none
```

*For clarification:*
If you want to convert a file called `input_file.png` to `output_file.png`, run the following command in your terminal (in the directory of `input_file.png`):

```
 convert -interlace none input_file.png output_file.png
```

The `convert` utility is part of the ImageMagick software package (https://imagemagick.org).

Now you can use output_file.png in your latex document without a warning.